# Check if name already exists in the database using Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my DBhelper.java codes... Help me to check db while storing the data

```
package com.example.sebastian.dblist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table contacts " +
                        "(id integer primary key, name text,email text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertContact(String name, String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);

        contentValues.put("email", email);
        db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("select * from contacts where id=" + id + "", null);
    }

    public boolean updateContact(Integer id, String name, String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("email", email);

        db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteContact(Integer id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("contacts",
                "id = ? ",
                new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts()
    {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(!res.isAfterLast()){
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)) +"\n"+res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

How can I check if a name is already present in the database while inserting value from the text field?

Comment: You want to insert data if it does not exists and if it exist disregard the insertion, Is that what you want to achiever?

Comment: You should just try the insertion and handle the failure that results if you violate the key integrity constraints. Doing it in two steps is wasteful and error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you run a statement first to check if the name exists like:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACTS WHERE NAME = ?
```

If the result is empty you can add the contact and return true.
If the result is > 0 you return false.

Edit: 
You can extend your `insertContact`-method like:

```
public boolean insertContact(String name, String email) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

// Check if name exists
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM CONTACTS WHERE NAME = ? ", new String[]{ name } );

// If name doesn't exist -> add
if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);

        contentValues.put("email", email);
        db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
        return true;
    }

    // else -> return false and print a Toast e.g.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: a recommendation , you should add little more explanation and code  , will add more up-votes to your answer and accepted quickly

Comment: can you explain.?

Comment: whats the false condition..? how to display it.?

Comment: we need to see the part of your code where you call your "insertContact"-method

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cur=  db.rawQuery( "select name from contacts where NAME  = ?", new String[]{ "abc" } );
```

or

```
Cursor cur=  db.rawQuery( "select name from contacts where NAME LIKE " + "abc");
```

This will search for "abc" in contacts.

```
if(cur.getCount() > 0){
    //name is present
}
```

Comment: No success which any answer?